# Rabbit trying to connect on test spring boot

Tags: java, spring, junit, rabbitmq, mockito

I want to disable the Rabbit on @Test method. I tried using the doNothing.when(rabbit.class) method, but it's not working.

Can you help me find a way to prevent the connection to Rabbit?

Thanks

```
2023-02-06 19:39:58.519  INFO 75 --- [ntContainer#0-1] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: localhost:5672
2023-02-06 19:39:58.522 ERROR 75 --- [ntContainer#0-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Failed to check/redeclare auto-delete queue(s).

org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:602) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:725) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:252) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:2180) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2153) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2133) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueInfo(RabbitAdmin.java:463) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(RabbitAdmin.java:447) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.attemptDeclarations(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1930) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.redeclareElementsIfNecessary(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1911) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.initialize(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1377) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1223) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Comment: Searching SO gave me the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44927085/prevent-rabbitlistener-in-spring-rabbit-from-trying-to-connect-to-server-during - Are the answers there helpful to you?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what you are trying to do if you running unit tests that should not be a problem since unit tests do not require loading the application context. On the other hand, if you running integration tests `@SpringBootTest` that requires you to load your application context and inject your Beans. You have 2 solutions:

1. Either annotate your services that require RabbitMq with `@MockBean`.
2. Use test containers to spin up a rabbitMq testing environment.

It would be more helpful to provide more details about the kind of test you are running and how you have written your test.